# Rails and Assigining Association Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, associations, field, assignment-operator, has-one

I was actually going through different associations and came up to something which I find a bit odd.

I have an association

```ruby
class Account < ApplicationRecord
end

class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :account
end
```

migration file

```ruby
class AddSupplierToAccount < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :accounts, :supplier, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

As I was studying I didn’t make it bidirectional.

I went in to the Rails console and created an account object as well as a supplier object. I then assigned the account object like so:

```ruby
supplier.account = account
```

but without saving the supplier object the transaction got commited to the database at the time of assignment. Should this be the way or am I doing anything wrong? If this is the way why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `belongs_to :supplier` under `Account` then review this page as to why you should:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Really important as a rails developer to read the entire Rails Guide for the version of rails you are using, tons of useful information there and probably 80% of the common rails issues can be solved by the information it contains.

Comment: Thanks..When I red down it had the answer to the question. when the object gets saved?

Comment: I'd have to see exactly how you setup the `account` object before that assignment. However, typically I would just explicitly define the supplier when creating the account. `Acount.create(..., supplier_id:  supplier.id, ...)`. I try to avoid using associations that way, as it can get messy and it's less obvious what you are doing.